# Specific Folder save & read

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm developing a game for mi Advance Algorithm class, but I'm having a problem with the read and save. I want to save the "fields" on a .txt file but on a specific folder in my solution. I want to create 1 file per field, and I want to read all the .txt files on that specific folder when I load the solution. The user must not send any address for saving or reading, that must be done by default by the program. I'm actually using this :

```
FILE* arch =fopen("Tableros.tbl","wt");
    if(arch==NULL)return;
```

Same thing for reading. But I can only read one file, and I want to detect or read all .txt on that specific folder. Any ideas or functions that can help?
I'm using visual studio 2010 c++.

Comment: you should use Boost file system API. Also, check against `null_ptr` rather then 'NULL'

Answer (score 1):

Use [GetCurrentDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to retrieve current process directory. Then use search in the directory ([FindFirstFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [FindNextFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and other) to detect and read all files in cycle.

Comment: full name of every file in the directory. Then you can open it with fopen()

Comment: OH, then i can just open the path! Sounds great. And how do i save in that specific folder? ive always saved my files on the debug folder by default

Comment: you have path, so what's the problem?

Comment: it's worth pointing out that these are platform specific functions. Ideally you should use Boost file API to provide cross platform support.

Comment: yeah, I know. But he didn't say anything about cross platform so I thought that these functions would suit his needs

Comment: "...\\debug\\Tableros\\1.tlb" , thats the address that i send to freopen, but i guess the "..." are not working. I mean i want to save it on the debug folder, creating a new one named "tableros" but its returning me NULL .

Comment: I still suggest you make use of Boost